# How to change a char in a String - replacing letters java

Tags: java

Simular topics were not able to solve my problem.
I need to change the char `'a'` to `'x'` in an given String `str`.

Example: "abc" = "xbc". I am only allowed to use `substring(), charAt()` - no `replace()` method.

My code so far:

```
public static String ersetze(String text){
    for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++){

        if(text.substring(i, i+1).charAt(i) == 'a'){
            text.substring(i, i+1) = 'x'; 
        }
    }
    //return statement
}
```

Now the error is `text.substring(i, i+1) = 'x';`that the left assignment must be a variable - clear. But how to assigne the letter to a variable now? If I declare a `char x;` how to put that `x` in the String to replace the letter?

Comment: Convert the String to a char array and work on it. Then convert it back to a new String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you REALLLLLY need this and you are limited to the methods you mentioned then you can do this each time you find requested char:
`text = text.substring(0, i) + x + text.substring(i + 1);`

Comment: @junxi, No worries! Just wanted to mention that this method is non efficient, creates lots of unnecessary strings and please never do this in real life

Answer (score 5):

`String` is [immutable](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/why-string-is-immutable-in-java/) in Java, so you cannot replace a letter of a String. You need to create a new String.

You can convert the String to an array of chars and changing only the needed ones, then create a new String from this array:

```
public static String ersetze(String text){
    char[] letters = text.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
        if (letters[i] == 'a') {
            letters[i] = 'x';
        }
    }

    return new String(letters);
}
```

Comment: User mentions that he's restricted on usage of API, otherwise he could have done .replaceAll()

Comment: @P.An. It's impossible to do with just `charAt` and `substring`. You need at least `+` or `toCharArray`. StringBuilder is equivalent to that.

Comment: @Thilo, check my answer below which uses just `+`

Comment: That's what I am saying. `+` is equivalent to StringBuilder.

Comment: Edited my answer prioritizing the approach using array of chars

Comment: didnt know about the toCharArray() method. worked great, thanks alot.

Comment: @junxi this solution is more efficient that the accepted one because it does not make a lot of concatenations (which generate new strings at each iteration). We create only one string at the moment we return it.

Answer (score 5):

String can not replace with character. First Need to create character array & then replace.

```
public static String ersetze(String text){
    char[] result = text.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        if(result [i] == 'a'){
            result[i] = 'x';
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a character array (included in the java API), iterate through the array and replace all the "a"'s with "x"'s in the char array and then change it back to a string.